# Bloomberg Api for Python: Parts of result missing in response

Tags: python, blpapi

I'm using bloomberg api for python to get the option data. Firstly, I got all the symbols of option chain. Then I used them to get the bid and ask prices. Through function getOptionChain, there are more than 400 options and I checked the result , it was fine. However, when I run the getPX function, I got only 10 results in the end. Could anyone help me looking into this? Thanks in advance!

```css
import blpapi
import pandas
import csv
options = blpapi.SessionOptions()
options.setServerHost('localhost')
options.setServerPort(8194)

SECURITY_DATA = blpapi.Name("securityData")
SECURITY = blpapi.Name("security")
FIELD_DATA = blpapi.Name("fieldData")
FIELD_ID = blpapi.Name("fieldId")
OPT_CHAIN = blpapi.Name("OPT_CHAIN")
SECURITY_DES = blpapi.Name("Security Description")


def getOptionChain (sec_list):
    session = blpapi.Session(options)
    session.start()
    session.openService('//blp/refdata')
    refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
    request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")
    for s in sec_list:
        request.append("securities",s)
    request.append("fields", "OPT_CHAIN")
    cid = session.sendRequest(request)
    try:
        # Process received events
        while(True):
            # We provide timeout to give the chance to Ctrl+C handling:
            ev = session.nextEvent(500)
            response = []
            for msg in ev:
                if cid in msg.correlationIds():
                    securityDataArray = msg.getElement(SECURITY_DATA)
                    for securityData in securityDataArray.values():
                        fieldData = securityData.getElement(FIELD_DATA)
                        for field in fieldData.elements():
                            for n in range(field.numValues()):
                                fld = field.getValueAsElement(n)
                                response.append (fld.getElement(SECURITY_DES).getValueAsString())
            # Response completely received, so we could exit
            if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
                break
    finally:
        # Stop the session
        session.stop()
    return response



def getPX (sec_list, fld_list):
    opt_chain_list = getOptionChain(sec_list)
    session = blpapi.Session(options)
    session.start()
    session.openService('//blp/refdata')
    refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
    request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")
    for s in opt_chain_list:
        request.append("securities",s)
    for f in fld_list:
        request.append("fields",f)
    cid = session.sendRequest(request)
    try:
        # Process received events
        while(True):
            # We provide timeout to give the chance to Ctrl+C handling:
            ev = session.nextEvent(500)
            response = {}
            for msg in ev:
                if cid in msg.correlationIds():
                    securityDataArray = msg.getElement(SECURITY_DATA)
                    for securityData in securityDataArray.values():
                        secName = securityData.getElementAsString(SECURITY)
                        fieldData = securityData.getElement(FIELD_DATA)
                        response[secName] = {}
                        for field in fieldData.elements():
                            response[secName][field.name()] = field.getValueAsFloat()
            # Response completely received, so we could exit
            if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
                break
    finally:
        # Stop the session
        session.stop()                   
    tempdict = {}
    for r in response:
        tempdict[r] = pandas.Series(response[r])
        data = pandas.DataFrame(tempdict)
    return data
                

sec = ["IBM US Equity"]
fld = ["PX_ASK","PX_BID"]
getPX(sec,fld)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've got the "response = {}" in the wrong place.
Currently you're clearing at each iteration of your loop so each event coming in refills it.
If you shift the "response = {}" to just before "While(True):" each iteration will append to it rather than clearing and refilling.

The same is true of the first function, but the bulk data comes back in a single event in this case.  If you were using multiple securities you would see the same issue (a single Bloomberg refdata (partial) response contains data for at most 10 securities).